# Conditionally replace values in PowerShell object

Tags: powershell, foreach, pscustomobject

I have an array of PSCustomObject contained in a variable named `$attendance`.

```
event name date       present
----- ---- ----       -------
A01   Mika 2021-02-22 1
A01   John 2021-02-22 0
B03   Mika 2021-02-24 0
B03   John 2021-02-24 1
```

The `present` column values must be modified to the following:

```
event name date       present
----- ---- ----       -------
A01   Mika 2021-02-22 Yes
A01   John 2021-02-22 No
B03   Mika 2021-02-24 No
B03   John 2021-02-24 Yes
```

I can change it with a `ForEach-Object` loop, but this iterates through the entire object.

```
$attendance | 
   ForEach-Object { 
      if ($_.present -eq '1') { $_.present = 'Yes' } else {$_.present = 'No' } 
   }
```

To shorten the code, I tried variations of the following, but I couldn't get it to fold back into the `$attendance` variable.

```
$attendance.present.replace('1','Yes').replace('0','No')
```

Is there a one-liner or simpler method using dot notation to change the `present` column's values?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative could be to use `Select-Object` on this:

```
$attendance | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'present'; Expression = {('No','Yes')[[math]::Sign($_.present)]}} -ExcludeProperty present
```

Output:

```
event name date       present
----- ---- ----       -------
A01   Mika 2021-02-22 Yes    
A01   John 2021-02-22 No     
B03   Mika 2021-02-24 No     
B03   John 2021-02-24 Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way to update all the values without using a loop but you can **shorten** your code to

```
$attendance | % {$_.present = @('Yes', 'No')[$_.present -eq '0']}
```

Another option might be to **add a custom property** doing the conversion

```
$attendance | 
    Add-Member -Name 'yesno' -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {
        return  @('Yes', 'No')[$this.present -eq '0']
    }
```

**Example** <sub>Note that my csv delimiter is a comma so change accordingly</sub>

```
$attendance = @'
event,name,date,present
A01,Mika,2021-02-22,1
A01,John,2021-02-22,0
B03,Mika,2021-02-24,0
B03,John,2021-02-24,1
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
$attendance | Add-Member -Name 'yesno' -MemberType ScriptProperty -Value {return  @('Yes', 'No')[$this.present -eq '0']}

$attendance | ft -a

event name date       present yesno
----- ---- ----       ------- -----
A01   Mika 2021-02-22 1       Yes
A01   John 2021-02-22 0       No
B03   Mika 2021-02-24 0       No
B03   John 2021-02-24 1       Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, using dot notation like `$attendance.present` creates a new array which cannot be used to manipulate the original array of `PSCustomObject`.

Shortest I could come up with:

```
$attendance.foreach({ $_.present = ('No', 'Yes')[ $_.present ] })
```

This works whether `present` is an integer or a string. PowerShell automatically converts strings to integer when used to index an array.

Slightly longer, using [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false) (requires PS7+):

```
$attendance.foreach({ $_.present = $_.present -eq 0 ? 'No' : 'Yes' })
```

I prefer the latter one as it is easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

By using the `Replace()` method you're just manipulating the string stored in present, it will not update the value on `$attendance`, there is no string method to do it either.